# use pipe return html tag with style in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I couldn't get style of element I set which is returned by my pipe.

**pipe code**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'tagColour'
})
export class tagColourPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return '<span style="color:red">${value}</span>';
  }

}
```

**page.pug**

```
.state([innerHTML]="item.tagList|tagColour")
```

Despite I set the style attribute in return function, DOM is rendered pure `span` without `style`. Oddly enough,class is work.

Now the one deal is set `class` then set `ViewEncapsulation`  to `None`.But the ViewEncapsulation is not a great solution because of `webpack inline style`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't misuse pipes this way.

Comment: I really don't understand why you're using pipes for this.. Anyway, can you try this? `.state --- NEW LINE --- span([style.color]='tagColour') {{ item.tagList }}`

Comment: This is not the way you can implement pipe just to change the color or implement style.

Comment: @developer033 it works if  set return colour code and `style.color = 'item.tagList | tagColour '`.

Comment: I simplifed my code. I have random paragraph and I want to highlight the keyword what I set.

i.e. the program produce long context , I want to highlight every letter for 'X'.
the html would show like    `x`-ray.

Answer (score 1):

The string you return doesn't bypass Angular's built-in sanitization. In order to return html with your styles, import the following:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

then

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(your_html_string);
```